# How do I align divs?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have three images that I am trying to align with `display: flex`, I see that those div's interfere with each other, I just can't get them to go side by side with another, so those divs overlap.
I made a JSFiddle to explain it better [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hftwqepz/).

```css
.top-section-hover {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10em;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 2;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 96%;
}

.top-section-hover img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: top ease 0.5s;
    left: 0;
}

.top-section-hover img.active {
    top: -30px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cover-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-section-hover span.active2 {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-section-hover">
      <span class="hover-cover-left">
        <a href="#" class="cover-left-content">
          <img src="https://www.4metri.lv/upload/iblock/95c/95c14a70011a4c90c37656d71c1c7f43.png" alt="" class="cover-img">
          <span class="cover-title">Birojam</span>
        </a>
      </span>
    
      <span class="hover-cover-middle">
        <a href="#" class="cover-left-content">
          <img src="https://www.4metri.lv/upload/iblock/28e/28e0b8c52db48dd56e0c0bfcccb445ff.png" alt="" class="cover-img">
          <span class="cover-title">Mājai</span>
        </a>
      </span>
    
      <span class="hover-cover-right">
        <a href="#" class="cover-left-content">
          <img src="http://4metri.lan/public/..\resources\images\4metribildelabi.png" alt="" class="cover-img">
          <span class="cover-title">Pasākumiem</span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image: The target]

This is the desired state, they all ling up side by side

Comment: The first thing to do would be to make the images *the same basic size*.

Comment: Then make them responsive by adding `max-width:100%`.

Comment: Hi @MrLucky2243,
I first noticed, that the images are of different sizes.
What do you want them to align on?
From what I can tell, they should all line up in the center. This would make the text jump (because of different image height).
What is the target state?

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki Hey, I added a picture of how I want it to look like

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking like this?

```css
.top-section-hover {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10em;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-grow: 2;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 96%;
}

.top-section-hover img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: top ease 0.5s;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.top-section-hover img.active {
    top: -30px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cover-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-section-hover span.active2 {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-section-hover">
            <span class="hover-cover-left">
                <a href="#" class="cover-left-content">
                    <img src="https://www.4metri.lv/upload/iblock/95c/95c14a70011a4c90c37656d71c1c7f43.png" alt="" class="cover-img">
                    <span class="cover-title">Birojam</span>
                </a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="hover-cover-middle">
                <a href="#" class="cover-left-content">
                    <img src="https://www.4metri.lv/upload/iblock/28e/28e0b8c52db48dd56e0c0bfcccb445ff.png" alt="" class="cover-img">
                    <span class="cover-title">Mājai</span>
                </a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="hover-cover-right">
                <a href="#" class="cover-left-content">
                    <img src="https://www.4metri.lv/upload/iblock/95c/95c14a70011a4c90c37656d71c1c7f43.png" alt="" class="cover-img">
                    <span class="cover-title">Pasākumiem</span>
                </a>
            </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.top-section-hover {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10em;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 2;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 96%;
    align-items:center

}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation. In this case you could point out that you added `align-items:center` and what it does.